# Finding trends from ordinal / likert responses

Tags: spss, ordinal-data, likert

I have two ordinal variables, ranked on a 1-5 Likert scale, and a categorical variable of age groups.  What I would like to is extract significant (or determine and identify the existence of) homogeneous groups from the categorical variable.  A simple example would be:

Variable_1 (Likert 1-5): Do you like chocolate?
Variable_2 (Likert 1-5): Do you like fruit?
Variable_3 (Categorical 15-25,26-35,36-45, etc.): Please select your age.

From this I'm looking for significant relationships between the responses of Variable_1 and Variable_2 based upon the age group.  Examples could be subjects between 16-25 liked chocolate but do not like fruit; conversely subjects between 56-65 liked fruit and not chocolate.

What statistical test / method could I use in this circumstance?

Note 1: at the moment I believe that cross-tabs is probably my best bet here with possibly the recoding Variable_1 and Variable_2 into a dichotomous dependant variables - which appears to simplify the results.

*Note 2: for those that are interested, I posted this question yesterday and by all account it was rather confusing and placed on hold, although feel free to [check it out](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/163369/extracting-meaningful-demographic-data-from-ordinal-likert-responses-in-spss).*

Note 3: using SPSS (if that helps)

Comment: Note that Variable_3 is still interval, although it is discrete (binned). You may use it as interval or as ordinal - decision is on you.

Comment: What is your hypothesis? Asking a precise question will point towards which test is the most appropriate to run. It's a bit confusing that you say "Examples could be subjects between 16-25 liked chocolate but do not like fruit", but also "I'm looking for significant relationships between the responses of Variable_1 and Variable_2". If you are trying to describe the frequency of participants liking fruit and dchocolate across age groups you ' d have to perform a different test compared to the one you 'd chose if the question was "does liking frut have an effect -or co-occur- with liking of

Comment: cont'd: chocolate?"

Comment: I guess that's the thing - there is no hypothesis in this case.  I am using Spearman's to determine whether a correlation exists (that's my initial hypotheses) between Variable_1 and Variable_2 - but I'm looking for an insight into the relationship.  Hence whilst a cross-tab can provide some indication of trends, I'm looking for guidance whether that's a) good approach and b) is there a better test or strategy to adopt (e.g. look for strong groups in a cross-tab then perform another correlation or use another technique to test whether an association exists).